# Вывод контента если товар относится к определенному атрибуту

Tags: php, wordpress

Сайт на WordPress с плагином WooCommerce. Товары разделяются на разные атрибуты (вариативные товары). Помогите разобраться, как сделать вывод разного контента для разных атрибутов? Пыталась через такой код, но постоянно ломается сайт:

```
<?php 

$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// Get the product attribute value(s)
$tableattribute = $product->get_attribute('rylko', 'rylko-ru');

// if product has attribute 'pa_color' value(s)
if( ! empty( $tableattribute ) ){
// do something

<div class="table_size">
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/rylkotable.jpg"><?php _e('Таблица','helas'); ?></a>
</div>

} else {
// No product attribute is set for this product

<div class="table_size">
    <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/tab.png"><?php _e('Таблица','helas'); ?></a>
</div>

}

?>
```

Comment: [get_attribute](https://wp-kama.ru/function/WC_Product::get_attribute) принимает 1 параметр, а не 2. А так включите дебаг и смотрите какие ошибки еще есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибки в php синтаксисе, не хватает открывающих и закрывающих элементов, попробуйте так

```
<?php 
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// Get the product attribute value(s)
$tableattribute = $product->get_attribute('rylko', 'rylko-ru');

// if product has attribute 'pa_color' value(s)
if( !empty( $tableattribute ) ){
// do something
?>
<div class="table_size">
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/rylkotable.jpg"><?php _e('Таблица','helas'); ?> 
</a>
</div>
<?php
} else {
// No product attribute is set for this product
?>
<div class="table_size">
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/tab.png"><?php _e('Таблица','helas'); ?></a>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Все ровно крошится. Может ошибка в этой строчке ?
$tableattribute = $product->get_attribute('rylko', 'rylko-ru');

Comment: По самому коду не знаю что сказать, так как не могу его проверить. Просто увидел явные ошибки в синтексисе.